# IPv6 Routing: Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address

Tags: routing, ipv6, ping, subnet

I need a help with IPv6 routing, I have setup a Linux box with a IPv6 interface on `eth2`, and this interface is bonded with interface `bond0`

Details as below

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 
DEVICE=bond0
NAME=bond0
TYPE=Bond
BONDING_MASTER=yes
IPADDR="10.54.48.82"
NETMASK="255.255.254.0"
GATEWAY="10.54.48.1"
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
USERCTL=no

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=fd00:10:6b50:4300::52/60
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fd00:10:6b50:4300::1
ONBOOT="yes"
DEVICE="eth2"

/sbin/ip -6 route show
unreachable ::/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 
fd00:10:6b50:4300::/60 dev bond0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 2591984sec 
fd00:10:6b50:4300::/60 dev eth2 proto kernel metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev bond0 proto kernel metric 256 
default via fd00:10:6b50:4300::1 dev bond0 metric 1 
default via fe80::7ae3:b5ff:feec:6500 dev bond0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1784sec hoplimit 64
```

Interface details as below:

```
ifconfig 
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.54.48.82  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.54.49.255
        inet6 fe80::2e76:8aff:fe51:1e40  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2c:76:8a:51:1e:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 560384  bytes 47006541 (44.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5254  bytes 1034248 (1010.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fd00:10:6b50:4300::52  prefixlen 60  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 2c:76:8a:51:1e:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 51
```

When I ping from the box,

```
ping6 fd00:10:6b50:4510::b3
PING fd00:10:6b50:4510::b3(fd00:10:6b50:4510::b3) 56 data bytes
From fe80::7ae3:b5ff:feec:6500%bond0 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fe80::7ae3:b5ff:feec:6500%bond0 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fe80::7ae3:b5ff:feec:6500%bond0 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
```

Getting `Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address`
 What could I be doing wrong here?
And how could I make the device ping the IPv6 address?

Comment: Why do you have both bond0 and eth2? It looks like you're ending up with one address on eth2 and a link local on bond0 with default routes out both. I suspect the traffic is exiting over the bond0 link local address and you're getting back the unreachable message from that device.

Comment: @BenFranske 
We have a customer setup to be done as above. Are the configurations missing anything?

Comment: I'm less familiar with the RedHat style configuration so I'm not sure, but I think I'd also need a diagram showing what the bond0 and eth2 connect to on the other end. I think your problem is the ipv6 traffic is getting routed out bond0 because it has an fe80 link local ipv6 address.

Comment: IP address configuration belongs on `bond0`, not `eth2`. Fix that first.